# VS Code or InternetExplorer.Application seems to be caching my script results?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

VS Code with Powershell extension

I am trying to parse a web page that I requires logging into, and am using InternetExplorer.Application
Its working up to a point, but now that I have logged in once with the script, its as if the script is caching my page results.  However, if I manually go the url, im prompted to login as expected.
Ive even taken out all the code that does the login actions, but I still get the page that is only shown after login.

What can I check regarding caching of results with using "InternetExplorer.Application" via powershell?
I have my IE options set to delete browsing history on exit, so shouldn't it clear things out?

In the excerpt below, I am showing the input elements, and the ones listed are in fact the ones that are only in the document AFTER logging in, but all the code to do the logging in has been removed.  Again, if I navigate to the browser manually in IE, I am prompted to login.  Something must be getting cached somewhere.

However, it also happens from the command line.  Not sure what to check to make sure something isnt getting cached.

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("www.something.com/client-portal")
$ie.visible=$true
$doc = $ie.Document

#-- see items on page
$doc.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName("input") | Select-Object Type,Name
... login code here, commented out then removed
```

**[update]**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752093%28v%3dvs.85%29

How can one pass one or more flags to the navigate method ?  Dont read from disk cache and dont add to history.

**[ update 2 ]**
I think it has something to do with either the app itself or powershell caching something.  Strange that navigating to the site manually results in expected behavior (being required to log in) yet its as if I am permantly seen as logged in when using powershell with IE automation.

Comment: F12 developer tools are your friend to see what's going on (even after launching IE from the script you can open it). Are you sure that the document is actually being cached? or is the web app written "badly"/lazy in the sense that what the page actually does is when it shows the login it just hides (i.e. visible=false) the rest of the page?

Comment: See update above.  Also, yes the page is definately the page content AFTER login, because I have already gone through the steps manually browsing and saving the html to file so I can see the elements I need to parse in each case.

Comment: Is the issue that you need to refresh the `$doc` object? e.g. `$doc = $ie.Document` (esp. when you manually do things it won't have the latest version)

Comment: Not really.  Notice the snippet above "... login code here, commented out then removed".  That is where I formerly had code that would login, and that worked fine.  Thr trouble is as I commented that code out to debug something before that, but when the page renders its as if it has already logged in.  I suspect its my powershell script being cached now.  There is no way the browser should be showing me the logged in view, if in fact nothing has logged me in.  Again, if I manually navigate to the same url as in the navigate method, I am shown the login page as expected.

Comment: Typically logins can be cached in cookies within the session, so that you may not need to login again. Basically the real question is, since you do: `$ie.visible=$true` does the visible IE page (with source F12) match what your code says it has?

Comment: Yes, it matches.